# permission issue on EVENT page after upgrade to 5.56.1

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I have upgraded from 4.7 to the latest version - there was no permission issue on EVENT pages but system reports an dependecy issue about Form core extension - to solve it I activated AuthX - I guess it was wrong so I did desactivated Civigrant + Form core + AuthX but now there is a permission issue on EVENT and REPORT

Comment: Comme je viens de la version  4.7 le civicrm.settings.php ne comportait pas de CIVICRM_CRED_KEYS et de CIVICRM_SIGN_KEYS => j'ai créé ces clés pour mettre à jour civicrm.settings.php /// le problème d'autorisation des pages EVENT persiste

Comment: the subject is closed: I restored the previous version of the files and databases to clean the useless extensions and in particular CiviGRANT, AFFORM, AuthX  then I updated CiviCRM again to the latest version without encountering this permission problem on the EVENT pages